# How to call my "Dialog Activity" from the notification in react-native (like Whatsapp Reply Button)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Im using push-notification for my application. I would like to use an action button where in the notification which can start an Dialog Activity from NativeModule Component(Just like Whatsapp reply button).

> This is my NativeModule function:

```
  @ReactMethod
    void navigateToExample() {
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null){

            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ExampleActivity.class);

            activity.startActivity(intent);
         }
    }
```

> Notification Button Listener:

```
  PushNotification.registerNotificationActions(['Reply!']);
        DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('notificationActionReceived', function(action){
          console.log ('Notification action received: ' + action);
          const info = JSON.parse(action.dataJSON);
          if (info.action == 'Reply!') { 

    **///Im calling the Dialog Activity**

    NativeModules.ActivityStarter.navigateToExample()


}
```

> ExampleActivity.class

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

        findViewById(R.id.call_callback_btn).setEnabled(true);
        findViewById(R.id.go_back_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.call_callback_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityStarterModule.triggerAlert("Hello from " + ExampleActivity.class.getSimpleName());
            }
        });
```

These codes are working very well while app is working in the foreground. But when app is closed, the new activity is not working/starting. Probably the problem is the navigateToExample() function cant get the Current Activity. I couldn't solve this problem. Is there any idea?

Comment: I do not remember that reactnative had processes in the background, I tried many times without success, even, the documentation of facebook in this regard indicates that there are non-native methods of reac native using java to achieve this, but it is not safe in many cases. This is the link [Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html)

Comment: Actually, i found my solution in your documentation link :).

Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyTaskService.class);